# How do I pass redux info into a navigator function? Or is there a different way to create a dynamic nav stack based on incoming data?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-navigation

So as a user, when I first log in, I'm taken to the HomeScreen. On this screen, there are these prompt values that come back from our API and thrown into Redux. These values determine whether or not I want to show these screens over the Home Screen.

I created a function to create a stack dynamically based on dummy data. It's working fine on my end, but I realized an issue when I tried to use the actual data. I need to pass these redux values over to my prompt-stack.js (which is a non react component so I can't use useSelector here... as far as I know?)

So here's an example of my code on the Home Screen, what causes the navigation to display this stack, the function that creates the stack, and the dummy data.

```js
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

const Home = ({ navigation }) => {
  const { show_prompt1, show_prompt2, show_prompt3 } = useSelector(
    state => state.reducer,
  );
  useEffect(() => {
    if (show_prompt1 || show_prompt2 || show_prompt3) {
      navigation.navigate('PromptStack');
    }
  }, [show_prompt1, show_prompt2, show_prompt3]);

  return <View />;
};

// PROMPT STACK

import { Prompt1, Prompt2, Prompt3} from './screen-prompts'
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';

const dummyData = {
  show_prompt1: true,
  show_prompt2: true,
  show_prompt3: false,
};

const promptConfigs = [
  {
    id: 0,
    screenKey: 'Prompt1',
    screenName: Prompt1,
    valueToMatch: 'show_prompt1',
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    screenKey: 'Prompt2',
    screenName: Prompt2,
    valueToMatch: 'show_prompt2',
  },

  {
    id: 2,
    screenKey: 'Prompt3',
    screenName: Prompt3,
    valueToMatch: 'show_prompt3',
  },
];

const createRoutes = () => {
  let RouteConfigsObject = {};
  promptConfigs.forEach(item => {
    if (dummyData[item.valueToMatch]) {
      RouteConfigsObject = {
        ...RouteConfigsObject,
        [item.screenKey]: {
          screen: item.screenName,
        },
      };
    }
  });

  return RouteConfigsObject;
};

const RouteConfigs = createRoutes();
const initialRouteName = Object.keys(RouteConfigs)[0];

const NavigatorConfig = { initialRouteName };

const PromptStack = createStackNavigator(RouteConfigs, NavigatorConfig);
```

export default PromptStack;
How would I swap out the dummy data with the redux data instead in this situation or what else can I do to figure this out?
Thanks!

I'm using React Navigation v4 btw

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible in React Navigation 4, but it is in React Navigation 4 using
`import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native'`

Here's what I'm doing instead:

```js
const screenData = [
{screen: 'Prompt1', value: show_prompt1},
{screen: 'Prompt2', value: show_prompt2},
{screen: 'Prompt3', value: show_prompt3},
]
```

In my useEffect, I run a forEach to check which values are true and pushing them into an array. The array is saved in my state. Once that's done, I use another useEffect, to navigate to the next screen with:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    if(screensStateData.length > 0){
        navigation.navigate(screenStateData[0], {screenStateData: 
        screenStateData.slice(1)})
    }
},[navigation])
```

My actual code has a few more conditions but I'm just creating an example.
So when I'm on my next screen, I can grab the param, do what I need to do, and then navigate again to `navigation.navigate(screenStateData[0])` since I already removed the first screen from the array.

There's a few more things I have to do but it's so far working!